# Extracting data from an XML document without using an XML parser

Tags: c#, xml, regex

Here's some lines of the document:

```
  <div class="rowleft">
    <h3>Technical Fouls</h3>

    <table class="num-left">
      <tr class="datahl2b"> 
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>Players</td>
          </tr>
          <tr> 
            <td>DAL</td>
            <td>
              None</td>

          </tr>
          <tr> 
            <td>MIA</td>
            <td>
              Mike Miller</td>
            <td>
              Mike Miller, Jr.</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

I'm interested in extracting the `None` and `Mike Miller` and `Mike Miller, Jr.` from this. I tried using various XML parsers, but 1) the performance is abysmal and 2) the document is apparently not a properly formatted XML document.

One thing I've been thinking about is stripping the document of newlines, splitting it at something like `<tr>`, seeing which lines contain data (probably using `StartsWith()`), and extracting it with a regex. That would be efficient enough for my program (doesn't really matter that it takes half a second when downloading the document is five seconds), but I'm interested it alternative solutions.

Comment: The performance is abysmal? Can you show the code you've been trying?

Comment: @Tomalak: Sorry, it's long gone. But loading the document into a variable took 20+ seconds.

Comment: @Hui that sounds like the download taking time, not the loading. What happens if you split them into two different lines? One downloading and one starting the parser

Comment: @Oskar: Downloading it using `WebClient` takes 4-5 secs, so that's not the issue.

Comment: @Hui *"it's long gone"*? How can that be?

Comment: @Tomalak: I don't keep track of all the code I've ever deleted. I tried that several hours ago. I remember using `XmlDocument` and `XmlTextReader`.

Comment: @Hui Strange logic. How would you expect anyone to be able to tell you what's wrong when you don't keep the code that doesn't work?

Comment: @Hui. Just for info, the reason that your snippet is not XML well formed is that `&nbsp;` is not an predefined entity reference in XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

HTML generally isn't properly formatted XML, I suggest you use something like the [HTML Agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Trying to parse HTML with string manipulation and regexes is invariably going to be horribly error-prone.

If your document is not well-formed XML, I would recommend using the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)